# CSS customization for displaying bot icon beside bot response box

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to customize this html page, where bot icon need to appear beside the bot responses and also the space between two messages is also need to be reduced.

[image]

How can I achieve this? the bot icon is displaying in users margin.

Comment: html body:
<body>
<div class="user-bar"></div>
<p class="user-box">hi</p>
<div class="bot-bar"></div>
<p class="response-box">Hi! I'm your virtual assistant!</p>
<div class="bot-bar"></div>
<p class="response-box">How May I help you?</p>
<div class="user-bar"></div>
<p class="user-box">login issue</p>
<div class="bot-bar"></div>
<p class="response-box">sure I can help you with this</p>
<div class="bot-bar"></div>
<p class="response-box">Please confirm your email id.</p>
</body>

Comment: * {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
width: 100%;
flex: 1;
min-height: 580px;
height: 100%; 
width: 270px;
background-color: #f4f4f4;
}
.user-bar{
height: 35px;
width: 35px;
background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTwxLzR_wVDg6DKEiQ90XGffgrZLF7_s_vaPA&usqp=CAU');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: right;
margin-right: 10px;
float: right;
}

Comment: .bot-bar{
height: 35px;
width: 35px;
background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQhgCkQbZmKeeMEys7nRNSem1zMFlYODegmmw&usqp=CAU');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
margin-left: 5px;
  }

Comment: .user-box {
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 12px 0 8px 12px;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  width: max-content;
  max-width: 170px;
  background-color: rgb(0,58,111);
  color:#fff;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: arial;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 2px #cbe9ff; 
  white-space: normal;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  float: right;
  font-family: Calibri, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif !important;
  font-weight: 100 ;
}

Comment: .response-box {    
  margin-top: 15px;             
  border-radius: 0 12px 12px 8px;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  width: max-content;
  max-width: 220px;
  background-color: #ffff;
  color: #156c8a;
  position: relative;
  clear: right;
  margin:5px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: arial;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc; 
  white-space: normal;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin-left: 40px;
  font-family: Calibri, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif !important;
  font-weight: 100px ;
}

Comment: I was unable to add this entire HTML and css in post. but I want the solution for this case. so please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; } body{ overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; width: 100%; flex: 1; min-height: 580px; height: 100%; width: 270px; background-color: #f4f4f4; } .user-bar{ height: 35px; width: 35px; background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTwxLzR_wVDg6DKEiQ90XGffgrZLF7_s_vaPA&usqp=CAU%27'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: right; margin-right: 10px; float: right; }


.bot-bar{ height: 35px; width: 35px; background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQhgCkQbZmKeeMEys7nRNSem1zMFlYODegmmw&usqp=CAU%27'); background-repeat: no-repeat; margin-left: 5px; margin-top: -40px;}

.user-box { margin-top: 5px; border-radius: 12px 0 8px 12px; padding: 8px 8px; width: max-content; max-width: 170px; background-color: rgb(0,58,111); color:#fff; margin: 5px; text-align: left; font-size: 13px; font-family: arial; position: relative; box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 2px #cbe9ff; white-space: normal; word-wrap: break-word; float: right; font-family: Calibri, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif !important; font-weight: 100 ; }

.response-box { margin-top: 15px; border-radius: 0 12px 12px 8px; border: 1px solid; padding: 8px 8px; display: block; text-align: left; width: max-content; max-width: 220px; background-color: #ffff; color: #156c8a; position: relative; clear: right; margin:5px; font-size: 13px; font-family: arial; box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc; white-space: normal; word-wrap: break-word; margin-left: 46px; font-family: Calibri, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif !important; font-weight: 100px ; }
```

```html
<body> 
<div class="user-bar"></div> 
<p class="user-box">hi</p> 

<p class="response-box">Hi! I'm your virtual assistant!</p> 
<div class="bot-bar"></div> 


<p class="response-box">How May I help you?</p> 
<div class="bot-bar"></div> 
<div class="user-bar"></div> 
<p class="user-box">login issue</p> 


<p class="response-box">sure I can help you with this</p> 
<div class="bot-bar"></div> 

<p class="response-box">Please confirm your email id.</p> 
<div class="bot-bar"></div> 

</body>
```

Changes
1.`<div class="bot-bar"></div>`  should be after each `<p class="response-box"></p>`
2.`.bot-bar` added `margin-top: -40px;`
3.`.response-box` changed `margin-left: 40px;` to `margin-left: 46px;`